# In JsDoc should `[key: string]: any;` allow me to use any key value property?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am using npm pacakge jsonwebtoken, and the jwt.verify method. When I try to deconstruct the return value I get a intellisense error

```
Property 'userId' does not exist on type 'string | JwtPayload'.
```

My code looks like this.

```
({ userId } = jwt.verify(token, 'my_secret'));
```

When I look at the index.d.ts for jsonwebtoken it has this

```
export function verify(token: string, ...): JwtPayload | string;
export interface JwtPayload {
    [key: string]: any;
    iss?: string | undefined;
    ...
}
```

Shouldn't the `[key: string]: any;` allow me to create any key value property?

Why do i still get type errors and is there a way to get rid of them using jsdocs?

Comment: you probably need a type guard: `const result = jwt.verify(...); if ("userId" in result)) { ({ userId }) = result; }`. Type guard is needed here because the `verify` method could also return a string; so you can't just destructure `userId` without first making sure that you got `JwtPayload` from the `verify` method.

Comment: @Yousaf Im not sure how to mark your comment as "answered" but seems like type guarding was a successful solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use brackets to access the value then it will not complain.

Something like this

```
const payload = jwt.verify(token, 'my_secret'))

payload["userId"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a [typeof type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#typeof-type-guards) to check if the result is of type `object`:

```js
let userId;
const jwtPayload = jwt.verify(token, 'my_secret');
if (typeof jwtPayload === 'object') {
    ({ userId } = jwtPayload);
}
```

Or force the type to be `JwtPayload` by casting it:

```js
({ userId } = /** @type {jwt.JwtPayload} */(jwt.verify(token, 'my_secret')));
```

Comment: This gives a `'userId' does not exist on type 'JwtPayload'`.